# Do action right after entity created in SonataAdmin

Tags: entity-framework, symfony, sonata-admin

is there any way that I could config my SonataAdmin to do action right after the default CRUD?

The situation is that, I've got some classes, each class has a BCode, which must be created with the entity. BCode is a tweaked crc32 string. so I need a customized action to be able to create this code with entity.id

thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like [events](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/events.html#persistenceevent) is what you're looking for. [Example usage](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html) from documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your admin class extends the `vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/Admin/Admin.php` so you just have to implement the methods `postPersist` and `postUpdate`.

If you use doctrine as ORM you can also use [the doctrine events postUpdate and postPersist as described in the documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/events.html#postupdate-postremove-postpersist).